# How to apply an Object Style to a group of objects in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm using InDesign to create a manual containing slides and lines beside the slides to write notes. All the text boxes are linked and I want the spacing to be automatic. Is there a way to select my graphic frame (where I insert the slide pictures), and my lines for text and create an object style?

Comment: Are asking if you can have a "style" which includes things like spacing between different objects? I don't think that's possible. Styles are for appearance attributes on objects, not the relationship between separate objects. Master pages are used for common positioning of separate objects. Or use of the Library feature to easily save/duplicate common objects and their set up.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't what Object Styles do, but it is what Master Pages are for.

Since the text frame will be in the same place in each page, set it up as a Primary Text Frame on the master page. The resulting text frames will be threaded automatically in the document. You can also set a blank graphic frame on the master page. On document pages, Ctl-Shift-click to make it editable, then insert your slide.